# PHP - Unable to redirect from login page to home page

Tags: php, login-script

I'm facing the problem for my login system. The **home page (index2.php)** cannot be redirected from **login page (index.php)**. The login page doesn't redirect to home page when I clicked "Login" button although I entered the correct ID and Password.

Here's my code:

***index.php***

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<form action="checklogin.php" method="POST">
<div align="center">
    <table style="background-color:#9FF781" width="285" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td width="130"><div align="right"><strong>ID :</strong></div></td>
            <td width="159"><label for="admid"></label>
                <input type="text" name="admid" id="admid"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div align="right"><strong>PASSWORD :</strong></div></td>
            <td><label for="admpwd"></label>
                <input type="password" name="admpwd" id="admpwd"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><div align="center">
                <button type="submit" name="login">Login</button>
            </div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
```

***checklogin.php***

```
<?php 
    include('../../../Connections/fyp.php');
    session_start();
    $admid = $_POST["admid"];
    $admpwd = $_POST["admpwd"];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM acc_login WHERE id = '$admid' AND pwd = '$admpwd'");
    $row = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($admid != "" && $admpwd != "")
    {
        if ($row != "")
        {
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = $admid;
            header("Location: index2.php");
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Invalid ID or Password! Please try again!')</script>";
            exit('<a href="index.php"><strong>Go Back</strong></a> to Login Page');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('ID or Password field cannot be blank! Please try again!')</script>";
        exit('<a href="index.php"><strong>Go Back</strong></a> to Login Page');
    }
?>
```

***index2.php***

```
<?php
    include("session.php"); //check whether user was logged in.
?>
```

***session.php***

```
<?php
    include('../../../Connections/fyp.php');
    session_start();
    $verify = $_SESSION['loggedin'];
    $session = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM acc_login WHERE id = '$verify'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($session);
    $login_session = $row['id'];

    if(!isset($login_session))
    {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
?>
```

Comment: try giving full path eg. http://abcd.com/login.php

Comment: Thanks.. If it's local network I just change the path name to "localhost/smth/smth/index.php" ?

Comment: Is this all the code from session.php? Any other output after the php-part?

Comment: That's all for session.php. I include it inside index2.php and index2.php is displaying a table that shows the information in one of a table inside phpMyAdmin database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your files directories as follow:

1- in your checklogin.php

```
include('fyp.php');
```

2- in your session.php

```
include('fyp.php');
```

And remove the last `?>` PHP closing tag in your PHP files (it is a good practice), to avoid headers' issues, then place all your PHP files in the same folder, if your problem is solved, it means you need to carefully check the URL you are passing based on your project folder structure.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I followed your instruction and put all the PHP files into same folder and it's working fine!

Answer (score 1):

if header already sent then header function not work correctly. so it happens use this.

```
<?php
include('../../../Connections/fyp.php');
session_start();
$verify = $_SESSION['loggedin'];
$session = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM acc_login WHERE id = '$verify'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($session);
$login_session = $row['id'];

if(!isset($login_session))
{
    echo "<script>location.href='index.php'</script>";
}
?>
```

this is what i do when i need to redirect after sending header or even ob_end_flush(); has been called.

Comment: It's still cannot redirect to index2.php

Comment: instead of header("Location: FileName.php");  use  echo "<script>location.href='FileName.php'</script>"; in whole project because once you send header from server to client it can not be changed. Best Luck

Comment: Thank you for your solution. //echo "<script>location.href='index.php'</script>"; is working when ID or Password was wrong and redirect back to index.php AUTOMATICALLY :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried an absolute url to your home page?

**checklogin.php**

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/index2.php");
```

Comment: I was tried but it still cannot redirect to index2.php

Comment: Regarding to yatinadra tailors post, you should always put `exit;` after header() to make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to debug your code , Please put `die('debug');` (or any thing in die() function ) before `header("Location: index2.php");` and check the output , this will help you to reach the actual problem.
or also put `exit(1);` after header();